# Url Routing Placeholder Matching Regex

Tags: php, regex, model-view-controller, url-routing

I'm building my own framework for learning purposes and its going pretty well so far except for one thing, the routing.

Lets say the url is localhost/admin/view, I have no problem matching that route with the correct controller and actions. The issue arise when url has an id like the following : localhost/admin/view/12. Im trying to use placeholders im my routes array (the framework approach) that contains defined routes to match with the url.

Here is what the route array looks like:

```
public function getRoute() {
    $this->route = array(
        [
            'url' => "admin/view",
            'controller' => 'AdminController',
            'action' => 'viewPosts',
            'type' => 'GET'
        ],
        [
            'url' => "admin/view/{id}",
            'controller' => 'AdminController',
            'action' => 'viewPostById',
            'type' => 'GET'
        ],
        [
            'url' => "admin/store/posts",
            'controller' => 'AdminController',
            'action' => 'storePosts',
            'type' => 'POST'
        ],
    );
}
```

I don't know how to match the url with a value from the route array that has placeholder. Like if the url is localhost/admin/view/1 how do I match it with the value admin/view/{id} from the array? And afterwards how do I get the GET param easily from the url? I know getting the params should not be too hard but Im trying to get them without exploding the url and doing too many operation (maybe with a regex?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use other approach in the routes matching. I suggest you see how others frameworks do with it (search and see how .htaccess works).
So you should use regex to deal with the matches, in the case of the admin/view/{id} , you could consider something like this : `admin/view/.*`
For this case everything after the `admin/view/` will be your id.

You can also read the docummentation of others frameworks like cakephp : https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

In php we have function to get the query string : $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] (https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php)

Regards.

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain it very well but my .htaccess is redirecting everything to index.php with a clean url like the frameworks do. I was just asking for the placeholder like {id} because thats the way laravel works. Btw the admin/view/.* I had already tried something similar with admin/view/.\d*$ but I didn't find it pretty I wanted to be with the placeholders. Would you mind explaining a little bit how the internal mechanism of the frameworks usually work for routing, not how to use them but more like the way the frameworks handle the url the way they split it and dispatch etc?